# How to setup openssl on windows

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I have setup openssl according to [this guide](https://wiki.qt.io/Compiling_OpenSSL_with_MinGW)

when I tried to complie my openssl-based code, it is showing *fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory*

The screenshort from *msys2 mingw 64-bit* is shown below.

[image]

Please how can I fix this? When I run openssl in the terminal, it works correctly but the code to use it (like stated above) isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that using *msys2 msys* console fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can try vcpkg. It is a library package management tool. Very easy to install library like openssl on windows.